# MUI Slide animation smooth push out of elements

Tags: reactjs, animation, material-ui, slide

I am currently trying to use the React MUI [Slide](https://mui.com/material-ui/transitions/#slide) in a button over a card. The slide animation works well, however it snaps out the content over it to the top instantly when it mounts since the element is with full height when it mounts.

Does anyone have ideas on how to solve that. This is the structure currently:

```
      <Slide
        unmountOnExit
        key={2}
        direction="up"
        in={showLink}
        container={containerRef.current}>
        <Button
          sx={{
            mt: 1,
          }}
          variant="contained"
          color="secondary">
          Support now
        </Button>
      </Slide>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply `position: "absolute"` to the button and `position: "relative"` to the component to which `containerRef` refers, you will remove the block positioning of the sliding button and get the behavior that I think you want.

```
const containerRef = useRef();
[...]
<ContainerBox
  ref={containerRef} 
  sx={{ position: "relative", overflow: "hidden" }}
>
  <Slide {...slideProps} >
    <Button 
      sx={{ position: "absolute" }}
    >
      Button
    </Button>
  </Slide>
</ContainerBox>
```

---

Edit:

In response to the comment and to try and to get the text to transition along with the button on hover.

Since MUI `Slide` simply adds in-line transition styling to the child element, you can mimic the same behavior with some simple CSS.  By applying the same `transition` properties to both the text and button elements, they should act the same.  Also, you can pull the transition variables from the theme by the `useTheme()` hook.

eg:

```js
const theme = useTheme();

const transitionStyle = {
  position: "absolute",
  bottom: `${hovered ? "0px" : "-36px"}`,
  transitionProperty: "bottom",
  transitionDuration: `${theme.transitions.duration.standard}ms`,
  trasitionTimingFunction: `${theme.transitions.easing.easeIn}`
};

[...]

<Typography
  sx={{
    ...transitionStyle,
    marginBottom: "36px" //push the text up by the button height
  }}
>
  Stuff
</Typography>
<Button variant="contained" sx={transitionStyle}>
  Button
</Button>
```

Here's what I came up with: [CodeSandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-button-and-text-with-slide-6yv8tk?file=/src/App.tsx:255-523)

Comment: Thanks for the time taken to do that, it's a useful example, but what I want is the button to act like a block element, but to gradually push out the text (with the transition of the animation). I might be able to do it using the absolute positioning from your example and triggering a transform animation on the <Typography> though!

The GIF I have provided is a little misleading because of the low FPS it is being showed at. It seems like the animation is smooth when in reality the text snaps to it's pushed out position instantly.

Comment: Ah.  Alright.  Let me take a look at it.  It should be possible with a little CSS.

Comment: I updated the answer with one way to add the transition to the text along with the button.

Comment: Exactly what I meant! Amazing idea and job on the CodeSandbox. Solves the problem :)